# Trying in vain to covert javascript date time string to PHP DateTime

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

As sent from client: 'Mon Mar 14 2016 15:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)'

```
$btime = $jd["bookingtime"];

$btime = substr($btime, 0, strpos($btime, '('));

$jobdetail->bookingtime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($btime));
```

Records are stored in MySQL database as such: 2016-03-14 15:00:00

Comment: Which format do you want to store it as?

Comment: Year / Month / Date   24hr:Min:Sec

Comment: So, are you trying to store the time as per GMT zone? echo $jobdetail->bookingtime would give you that.

Comment: No, AEDT ....... , but the MySQL test server installed is probably storing it in GMT, at the moment I just need something that will work :)

Comment: What is the output of `date_default_timezone_get()`? It could be UTC, then you will have to set your timezone.

Comment: Yup, it's UTC. So that's what the web server / PHP engine is set at ?  I think I should keep it UTC and just subtract/add difference as necessary for display since users will be from varying timezones.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. I just have a doubt now about how the 0-12 or 0-24 (AM/PM) hours are handeled in your case. looks to be ok, but test carefully...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your PHP is set to UTC default time zone you can set it with `date_default_timezone_set()` and find your timezone. Have a look [here for australian timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.australia.php).

If you have access to your php.ini file, you can set in it the parameter [`date.timezone`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone) to the timezone you need. If the setting is not set, it will be UTC by default. AFAIK there should be a warning echoed when using `date`function in newer versions of php if there is no timezone set.

Else you can store it in UTC, as you mentionned, and convert to localtime according to your needs. If users are from many different timezones, UTC would be easier.

Date are automagically converted in the timezone you setted with date.timezone or with the function `date_default_timezone_set()` :

```
$d = 'Mon Mar 14 2016 15:00:00 GMT+1100';

$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($d));
var_dump($date);                        // echoes '2016-03-14 04:00:00'
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());  // echoes 'UTC'

date_default_timezone_set ('Europe/Zurich');
var_dump(date_default_timezone_get());      // echoes 'Europe/Zurich'
$date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime($d)); // echoes '2016-03-14 05:00:00'
var_dump($date);
```

Comment: Does the server automatically convert the dateTime string it receives from the client in the format I stated in my question to the UTC time or does this conversion have to be done manually for each dateTime and timezone type that comes from the client/browser ?